# Filter TLS in Wireshark or other monitoring tool

Tags: encryption, tls, webserver, wireshark, hardening

As part of the new best practices in hardening server communications I need to deny TLS 1.0 on the web server, before doing so I wish to identify the number of clients who connect with this level of encryption.

Therefore I would like to know how to filter incoming communications with different encryption methods like TLS 1. 0,  1. 1 and 1. 2.
If there is a different method to identify or quantify these communications which will be easier than whireshark I would be glad to hear about it.

Answer (score 9):

Try filtering by `tls.record.version`

For example, if you wanted to only display TLS v1.2 traffic then you could run `tls.record.version == 0x0303`

You can choose from the hex values below for the version that fits your needs.

Versions:

- 0x0300 SSL 3.0
- 0x0301 TLS 1.0
- 0x0302 TLS 1.1
- 0x0303 TLS 1.2

To avoid using the GUI or to automate this further you could also filter by using `tshark`.

---

Resources:

[Traffic Analysis of an SSL stash TLS session](https://web.archive.org/web/20200115073512/http://blog.fourthbit.com/2014/12/23/traffic-analysis-of-an-ssl-slash-tls-session/)

Thank you, [Duncan Howe](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/53503/duncan-howe) for the update.

Comment: The ideal solution would be a capture filter which would ignore all connections but the ones you're interested in

Comment: For later versions of Wireshark (not sure which version brought this in) the filter is now `tls.record.version`; the values remain the same though